# Entity Framework is not creating Tables in the Database on Migrate() method call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on a Blazor Server App. I also use Entity Framework. The targeted framework is .NET 7.0. I do have a Postgresql database. Now I have created `GameModel`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyBlazorApp.Data.Models
{
    [Table("Games")]
    public class GameModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Data { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I have also created a `GamesService` that looks like this:

```
using MyBlazorApp.Data.Models;

namespace MyBlazorApp.Data.Services
{
    public class GamesService
    {
        private readonly MyAppDbContext dbContext;

        public GamesService(MyAppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public List<GameModel> GetAllGames()
        {
            return dbContext.Games.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My `dbContext` looks like this:

```
using MyBlazorApp.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyBlazorApp.Data
{
    public class MyAppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<GameModel> Games{ get; set; }

        public MyAppDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyAppDbContext > options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I add my `DbContext` to the services:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
```

And this is how I add my `GamesService`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<GamesService>();
```

In the `Program.cs` I am also doing this:

```
var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyAppDbContext>();
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Somehow Entity Framework is not creating the `Games` table. Although I am calling the `Migrate()` method in `Program.cs` file.

Why is Entity Framework not creating the `Games` table in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

will *apply* outstanding migrations. You didn't mention *creating* any migrations.

Open the package manager console window and type `add-migration InitalModel`

Answer (score 2):

You should update the database in Design time before you run the program.

first, you'll have to install the [EF Core command-line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/)

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

your project should containes Nuget package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` to enable this ef tool

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

then create your migrations (this is important)

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

last step update your Database

```
dotnet ef database update
```

now if you go to your database, you will find table

you can follow this [tutorial on migrations overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)